# Making edittext show values

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i am new to android and i am trying to do this

[image: The required Image]

Please tell me how to do that when i enter some amount it should show up just like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, you might have to tweak the margins and text styles but this is what you want:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/container
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/amountLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/amount" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a relativelayout having one TextView(Amount), and one TextView(value).
Set background of EditText to #0000000, and relativeLayout's image you have displayed here.
Set TextView alignment to left_align_parent=true, and EditText's align_parent_right.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `RelativeLayout` having one `TextView` (Amount), and one `EditText` (value). Set background of `EditText` to `#0000000`, and `RelativeLayout`'s image you have displayed here. 
Set `TextView` alignment to

```
  left_align_parent=true
```

and `EditText`

```
    android:gravity="right"
```